# My @PostConstruct method is getting called everytime I delete the last element of a dataTable in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dataTable in JSF to show the phone numbers from a selected user.

Like the image below

[My DataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZz8L.png)

In this dataTable I have a column with a commandLink to delete the element. The commandLink is working fine except in one particular case : If I delete the element of the last row and I try to delete any other element my @PostConstruct method is called again and it throws an exception. I concluded that the exception is being called because the param that contains the id of the user is null.

My question is why is this bug triggered only when I delete the last row of the dataTable ?

```
nov 28, 2022 11:36:54 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/telefone.xhtml]
com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: An error occurred performing resource injection on managed bean telefoneBean
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:227)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:103)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:93)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:136)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.renderRow(GridRenderer.java:185)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.GridRenderer.encodeChildren(GridRenderer.java:129)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:417)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderException
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.invokePostConstruct(BeanBuilder.java:221)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at com.sun.faces.vendor.WebContainerInjectionProvider.invokeAnnotatedMethod(WebContainerInjectionProvider.java:113)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:655)
    at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:817)
    at managedBean.TelefoneManagedBean.init(TelefoneManagedBean.java:42)
    ... 72 more

nov 28, 2022 11:36:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [Faces Servlet] in context with path [/pos-java-maven-hibernate] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:341)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {

    String codUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
            .get("codigouser");
    
    daoUsuario = new DaoUsuario();
    daoTelefone = new DaoTelefone();
    telefone = new TelefoneUser();
    usuario = daoUsuario.pesquisar(Long.parseLong(codUser), UsuarioPessoa.class);
    lista = daoTelefone.consultarLista(usuario);

}
```

The code of my xhtml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:breadCrumb>
            <p:menuitem></p:menuitem>
            <p:menuitem value="Pagina Index" action="index.jsf" />
            <p:menuitem value="Pagina Primefaces" action="primefaces.jsf" />
        </p:breadCrumb>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="formulario">
        <h:messages showDetail="true" showSummary="false" id="msg"></h:messages>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel value="Usuário: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{telefoneBean.usuario.nome}" />
            <h:outputLabel value="ID " />
            <h:inputText value="#{telefoneBean.telefone.id}" readonly="true" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Numero: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{telefoneBean.telefone.numero}" required="true" />
            <h:outputLabel value="Tipo: " />
            <h:inputText value="#{telefoneBean.telefone.tipo}" required="true" />
            <h:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{telefoneBean.salvar}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    <h:form id="formularioTelefones">
        <p:dataTable rowStatePreserved="true" value="#{telefoneBean.lista}"
            id="tabelatelefones" var="tel">
            <f:facet name="header">Lista de Telefones</f:facet>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tel.id}" />
                <f:facet name="header">ID</f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{tel.numero}" />
                <f:facet name="header">Numero</f:facet>
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Tipo</f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{tel.tipo}" />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <f:facet name="header">Deletar</f:facet>
                <h:commandLink id="botaodeletar" action="#{telefoneBean.remover}">
                    <h:graphicImage url="resources/img/deletar.png" />
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{tel}"
                        target="#{telefoneBean.telefone}" />
                    <f:ajax execute="botaodeletar" render="@form :formulario:msg" />
                </h:commandLink>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I will explain the bug using this example, lets imagine I delete the row with id= 484.If I do this, I can delete any other row perfectly fine.
Now, lets say I delete the row 503. This row is going to be removed, but if I try to remove any other row my @PostConstruct method is going to be called again and it will throw an exception because the param "codigouser"(this is the param that gets the ID of the user I want)  will be null, BUT I still am able to add another number to the list and if I do this the table starts working again (with the same conditions)...

.[See the example of a dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IxfS.png)

First I thought the problem was on the method that I use to delete the phone number in the DB. Then I thought the problem was on the method that I use to get the list of phone numbers in the DB. Then I noticed that this bug just happens when I refresh the values of the dataTable. If I dont refresh the values on the dataTable then everything works perfectly fine, but the problem of course is that the phone numbers I remove still show in the table because I didnt refreshed it.

Edit :
The managed bean class

```
package managedBean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import dao.DaoTelefone;
import dao.DaoUsuario;
import model.TelefoneUser;
import model.UsuarioPessoa;

@ManagedBean(name = "telefoneBean")
@ViewScoped
public class TelefoneManagedBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UsuarioPessoa usuario; // the user
    private DaoUsuario daoUsuario; // dao to find the user in the database
    private DaoTelefone daoTelefone; // dao to find the phone numbers in the data base
    private TelefoneUser telefone; // Object used to save and delete the phone number

    private List<TelefoneUser> lista; // list of phone numbers from the user

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        String codUser = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                .get("codigouser"); // getting the user id
        
        daoUsuario = new DaoUsuario();
        daoTelefone = new DaoTelefone();
        telefone = new TelefoneUser();
        usuario = daoUsuario.pesquisar(Long.parseLong(codUser), UsuarioPessoa.class); // getting the user
        lista = daoTelefone.consultarLista(usuario); // getting the list of phone numbers

    }

    public void setUsuario(UsuarioPessoa usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public UsuarioPessoa getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public TelefoneUser getTelefone() {
        System.out.println("telefone");
        return telefone;
    }

    public String remover() throws Exception {
        daoTelefone.deleteId(telefone);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Informação:", "Telefone removido."));
        telefone = new TelefoneUser();

        return "";
    }

    public String salvar() {
        telefone.setPessoa(usuario);
        daoTelefone.salvar(telefone);

        telefone = new TelefoneUser();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Informação:", "Telefone Salvo."));
        return "";
    }

    public void setTelefone(TelefoneUser telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public DaoUsuario getDaoUsuario() {
        return daoUsuario;
    }

    public void setDaoUsuario(DaoUsuario daoUsuario) {
        this.daoUsuario = daoUsuario;
    }

    public DaoTelefone getDaoTelefone() {
        return daoTelefone;
    }

    public void setDaoTelefone(DaoTelefone daoTelefone) {
        this.daoTelefone = daoTelefone;
    }

    public List<TelefoneUser> getLista() {
        lista = daoTelefone.consultarLista(usuario);

        return lista;
    }

    public void setLista(List<TelefoneUser> lista) {
        this.lista = lista;
    }

}
```

The method used  to remove the phone number :

```
    public void deleteId(E entidade) throws Exception {
            Object primaryKey = HibernateUtil.getPrimaryKey(entidade);
            
            EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
    
            transaction.begin();
            
            entityManager.createNativeQuery("delete from "+entidade.getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()+" where id="+primaryKey).executeUpdate();
            
            transaction.commit();

            
    }
```

Comment: Is the correct entry deleted in the database? Whats the code of `telefoneBean`?

Comment: You need to post the entire Java class, including the import statements. If your bean is requestScoped this is expected behavior

Comment: @XtremeBaumer  
 
Just made an edit in the end with the method that I use to delete the phone number and the whole managed bean class.  The scope is ViewScoped

Comment: @JonathanS.Fisher 
This behavior is a little weird.It is like deleting the last row of the table is destroying my managed bean and when I try to delete any other row the managedBean is being created again so the PostConstruct method is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment section We found the problem. That was a rendering problem here:

```
<f:ajax execute="botaodeletar" render="@form :formulario:msg" />
```

Changed to this:

```
<f:ajax execute="@this" render=":formulario:msg :formularioTelefones:tabelatelefones" />
```

Comment: I said this is a bug because this weird behavior only happened when I tried to remove a row after I removed the last row of the table. It is like removing the last row of the table is crashing the system somehow and I am unable to remove any other row...
Now I made the change you suggested.  When I try to delete a row (after I removed the last row of the table) instead of throwing an exception the whole page is refreshed and the row that I tried to remove still there.  I made a 40s video showing the new behavior.
https://youtu.be/e-4J-LWFD_k

Comment: Thank you for the update. 
Now it looks like a rendering problem. Your <h:commandLink id="botaodeletar" action="#{telefoneBean.remover}"> is only rendering the <f:ajax execute="botaodeletar" render="@form :formulario:msg" /> . 

The button may also need to be rendered because after you delete the line, the button will have the wrong information about the 'tel" paramater. (Especially the last line)
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{tel}" target="#{telefoneBean.telefone}" />.

Comment: I'll try another way:
The "lista" has 5 items.
Then you delete the 3rd line.
The "lista" now has 4 elements, but the parameters of the buttons have not been updated.
Now delete the last line.
The last line points to the 5th element of "lista", which does not exist.
This is when the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your help,I found the solution. When you said its a rendering problem I decided to change this part of the code : 
 <f:ajax execute="botaodeletar" render="@form :formulario:msg" />
If I just remove the "@form" the page stopped refreshing like in the video but the table also  stop updating itself everytime I remove a row. So I decided to add the id of the form that contains the table and the id of the table :
<f:ajax execute="@this" render=":formulario:msg :formularioTelefones:tabelatelefones" />

Now everything is working fine, even in the ViewScoped  scope.